# Passing a column name as parameter to a stored procedure in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-update, dynamic-sql

I'm creating some stored procedures to manage my DB.
In particular, i want to create a stored procedore to edit a column, of a specific row, but i want to do it dinamically, passing the column name as an argument.

That's what i want to do

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.edit_myTable(
    IN key CHAR(16), 
    IN col VARCHAR(100), 
    new_value VARCHAR(200)
)
UPDATE myDB.myTable SET col = new_value
```

Using the parameter `key`i find the specific row in `myTable`that i want to edit, and i want to use the parameter `col` to edit just the column that i want.

I've already tried using `CONCATE()`or defining local variables, as i read on other topic, but i haven't find a solution.

Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need to use *dynamic SQL* :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.edit_myTable(
    IN key CHAR(16), 
    IN col VARCHAR(100), 
    new_value  VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    SET @s = CONCAT(
        'UPDATE myDB.myTable SET `', 
         col, '` = ', QUOTE(new_value),
         ' WHERE key = ', QUOTE(key)
    );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
DELIMITER;
```

Please note that, as commented by [Paul Spiegel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5563083/paul-spiegel), using a variable for column name creates a risk of SQL injection. One solution for improve security would be to make sure that the input `col` does exists in the target table, using MySQL information schema :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.edit_myTable(
    IN key CHAR(16), 
    IN col VARCHAR(100), 
    new_value  VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE col_exists INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO col_exists 
    FROM  information_schema.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLENAME = 'mytable' AND COLUMN_NAME = col;

    IF (col_exists != 1) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = CONCAT('Column ', col, ' does not exist in table mytable');
    END IF;

    SET @s = CONCAT(
        'UPDATE myDB.myTable SET `', 
         col, '` = ', QUOTE(new_value),
         ' WHERE key = ', QUOTE(key)
    );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
//
DELIMITER;
```

Comment: You need to enclose the `new_value` and `key`.

Comment: You better use [QUOTE function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_quote) for that. `col, '=', QUOTE(new_value)`. It's easier to read, and also injection save. However - the `col` parameter is still open to SQL injections.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel : I tried to provided a solution against SQL injection.

Comment: Not sure if that is 100% safe - but I like the idea. Last thing: `col` should be enclosed with backticks in the prepared statement. It could be a reserved word like "order" or contain a space.